# Full refund due to covid cancellation?

Tags: covid-19, emirates

Booking:
1. Leg: HKG - (DXB) - MUC (1. June 2020)
2. Leg: MUC - (DXB) - HKG (1. July 2020)

Class / Fare
Economy / Special

Emirates cancelled the 1. Leg of my booking due to covid 19.

I know want to know if I have the right for a full refund of my complete booking. I cannot and don't only want to use my 2. Leg.

Since emirates only offers vouchers, I want to ask here first and clarify the situation. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean HKG? And anyway, doesn't EU261 apply here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton No, Emirates is not an EU airline, and the first leg is flying into the EU, so EU261 doesnt apply here.

Comment: Oh yes, HKG of course.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only the Airline can answer seeing as the outcome of your request depends on their current cancellation policy which is inevitably subject to change due to the unknown evolution of the covid situation.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't understand this close reason. There's plenty of legitimate questions on this site which "only the airline can answer". Would it not be better to close as a duplicate of one of the canonical COVID-19 questions?

Comment: @MJeffryes The covid situation evolves so rapidly that most answers will soon be outdated. We discussed this on Meta. Having said this, by all means link to all the potentially useful questions you can find. We need all the help we can get. :)